# Excel if function with product formula

Tags: excel

I can't seem to find the right way of writing a formula for a cell. 
Purpose of the formula: showing the product of 2 cells if the result isn't zero, if it's zero, the cell should remain blank and not showing "0"
formula so far:

```
=IF((L29*I29)=0;"";L29*I29)
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Can you try like this `=IF(L29*I29=0;"";L29*I29)`

Comment: That works, don't know why I didn't came up with that :) thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this, it should work:

```
=IF(L29*I29=0;"";L29*I29)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a custom format.

There are four sections to a cells format.  Each defines how to display the value held in the cell dependent on what the value is.

**(positive);(negative);(zero);(text)**

I'd suggest the following which will display positives and negative numbers with two decimal places, *zero values won't be shown*, and any text as entered.

```
#,##0.00;-#,##0.00;;@
```

[Create or delete a custom number format](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-or-delete-a-custom-number-format-78f2a361-936b-4c03-8772-09fab54be7f4)